# Only variables should be passed by reference in class.base.sys.php on line 88

Tags: php

My Application Error

> Only variables should be passed by reference in
> D:\wamp64\www\sppd\factory\base\class.base.sys.php on line 88

My code

```
protected function loadMultiClass($path,$prefix,$codelist) {
    $codelist .= ",";
    $temp=explode(",",$codelist);
    for ($u=0;$u<count($temp);$u++) {
        if ($temp[$u] != "") {
            $className=$temp[$u];
            if (!isset($this->vars[$className])) {
                    $this->loadCode($path.$prefix.$temp[$u].".php",$temp[$u]);
                    $this->vars[$className]=& instantiate_class(new $className());
                    
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is line 88?